# How do I get a windows C# control to automatically update if the database table updates/inserts?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, data-binding

I have a listView WinForms-C# that I've binded to a database (MySQL) table but I can't seem to figure out how to have the listView automatically display the results when changes are made to the database table (update/insert) without the user having to fire an event i.e. button_click, timer_tick, etc...

Can someone please point me in the right direction. Any advice/solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
-Donald

Comment: Are you expecting the MySQL DB to send events/triggers to your code once something changes in its structure?

Comment: Is the change made by the application?  If not, how is the application to know that a change has occurred?

Answer (score 1):

**SQL does not support sending change events back from the database to the client.**

The events on the `DataTable` do not signal changes from the database. They signal changes to the `DataTable` itself.

If you want to see changes to the actual database, you have two choices:

1. The simple way to detect changes is to periodically execute a query, say every minute or every 5 minutes, and detect changes to the database;
2. If you require real time changes, the alternative is to have a messaging service. You could implement a WCF service to which you send a signal when you change the database. Then, other processes (including your own) can connect to this WCF service with a callback interface and receive these changes when they occur. This however only works if you have full control over changes to the database.

The first mechanism will give you periodic updates, like the old POP3 notifies. The second mechanism will give you real time updates.

Answer (score 0):

Your datasource should have an event on it that triggers when an update has occured. You could probably attach to that event and have that fire the refresh without user intervention--though you'll probably need to use a delegate to update the UI since it's firing from an event trigger.

*For clearity's sake, I am aware there is no way for SQL to flag a change back, I was under the impression they had a library that implemented the CRUD operations they were binding to, and there were events available to flag said changes. Having had the commentary below, i can now make a more informed decision*

**EDIT** Version 2

I would suggest creating a timer, as Pieter above suggested, and poll the database for changes. Use some value in the database as a counter to know when you need to grab updates from (i.e. if there is primary key in the table, keep checking against `WHERE key > last_key_receieved`)

Also, since you'll be working in another thread, you will need to make a method that will update the UI safely. Depending how many columns you have in the listView, the prototype will vary but the premise is the same:

```
Timer updateScoresTimer = new Timer();
updateScoresTimer.Tick += delegate
{
    // 1. grab the database info
    // 2. filter for post-worthy changes
    // 3. iterate over changes, passing the UI info to AddScore(...)
};
updateScoresTimer.Interval = 30000;
updateScoresTimer.Start();

public delegate void AddScoreHandler(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3);
public void AddScore(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)
{
    if (this.listView1.InvokeRequired)
        this.BeginInvoke(new AddScoreHandler(this.AddScore), new object[]{ arg1, arg2, arg3 });
    else
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(arg1);
        lvi.SubItems.AddRange(new string[]{ arg2, arg3 });
        this.listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, let me make sure I'm clear on this-you guys are saying that I should create an event that fires when a change is made to the table and notifies the winForm?

Comment: can you give me an example of what your talking about? or if you know if any links that cover what I'm looking for.

Comment: That's correct. Without knowing what you're binding the control to, I'm may be making a leap of faith in assuming the source has something that signals a back-end change. Under that same premise, this is assuming something the user is doing is triggering that forceful update (i.e. it's not a dormant client that grabbed the initial DB information, then another user somewhere made a change, and you're hoping that client will recognize the change). If the latter is true, your best bet is probably just to poll the DB for changes periodically and update as necessary.

Comment: I'll clearify - I have real-time data inserting into a database table and I want to display the the results of the table inserts if it meets a certain criteria, but I want to to happen automatically without the user having to click a button in order to display the results to eh listView

Comment: I understand that, but is this wrapped in a handler? Is there a library you're using, or using the SqlClient and just making direct calls and pushing the data in yourself? There are a lot of ways MySQL can be queried and the values pushed in to a control. Also, I need to understand what you imply by saying you want it to update on a change (an change the user did, a change another user separate from the application could have done, etc.)

Comment: So this is more like a "monitoring" client, where it sits on the sidelines and just watches new items going in the database, tests against a filter, and displays the results that are deemed appropriate? A timer running at a fixed-interval is probably your best bet then. Poll the DB, look for new rows (perhaps keep track of the PK and look for items greater than the last query) and show those that match,

Comment: example-I created a C# object that receives real-time sports scores(dataFeed) and inserts the scores via sql insert statement into a MySQL table. Now I have a WinForm that displays the scores from the table in a listView via a sql select query that I've been running on a timer, but I want to scores pushed to the listView without the user having to do anything.

Comment: oops I meant I want to listView to show the scores without the timer having to execute the C# method that sends the query to table and gets the results and displays them in the listview

Comment: Is the sports score feed and the winforms in the same application? Or are they two different processes?

Comment: Thanks Brad! I'm thankful that you gave me an illustration. I was basically doing what you're showing me but in a more crude way and my code was not as clean and well put together. I'm do a few tutorials on delegates and events so I can get a solid understanding of what your doing.