# C# How to: listening if new record is inserted in a mysql table

Tags: c#, mysql, events

I would like to create an event in c# that it triggers when a new record is inserted in a mysql table. I want to avoid to do polling the table every time.

Do you think it is possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a windows C# control to automatically update if the database table updates/inserts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247337/how-do-i-get-a-windows-c-sharp-control-to-automatically-update-if-the-database-t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DBMS such as MySQL is a multi user system, as such then only the database itself knows when data is inserted.

MySQL supports triggers which allow you to perform an action when some data is read, inserted, updated, deleted from a table.

Typically this is done to perform a similar action upon other tables in the system, but MySQL does support a feature known as UDF - User Defined Functions which will allow you to call external programs from the trigger.

I have not done this myself and only know the theory, but if you search for UDF for MySQL then I'm sure you can find some examples.

Here are some examples:

http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.de/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html

[Calling an url from a trigger in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215104/calling-an-url-from-a-trigger-in-mysql)

You can then use this to interact with your program.  But be careful with performance as the trigger is called synchronously.

It might be an idea to get the trigger to send a message via message bus, which you program can then listen for.